# Making self-adjusting table in latex

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to create self-adjusting table in latex. THis is going to be a big table so I need text to go to the next line if not enough space but I am not able to do this. I need to have 5 columns.
Below is the image of what I have managed but "description" is now going into the next cell. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me where I am going wrong. I have spent so much time on this
[image]

Code I am using,

```
    \begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
Author & Clustering Technique & Dataset & Description & Industry\\
\hline
\citeauthor{shen2009study} & Quantiles & Customer and Transaction Department store & RFM; Customer Lifetime Value; Target Marketing; Data Mining 
 &  Retail Store \\ 
 \hline
\citeauthor{aggelis2005customer} & Quantiles & E-Banking Dataset & Data Mining; e-banking; RFM analysis & Banking\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

EDIT: I also need it either to fit on one page or be able to continue in the next page.

Comment: Can you post your preamble? So we know the width of the page etc. ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 0):

Very belated answer...

To adjust the width of the column I have used `p{.1\textwidth}`, this is **paragraph alignment** with width of the column equal to `0.1` times the width of the text body (or other fraction of it).

For the table to continue in next page(s), if necessary, I have used the excellent environment `longtable` from the [package with the same name](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{.1\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.3\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|}
%\caption[Short caption]{Full caption}\label{longt}\\
\hline
% content of first header
Author & Clustering Technique & Dataset & Description & Industry\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
% content of following headers if the table continues in other page(s)
Author & Clustering Technique & Dataset & Description & Industry\\
\hline
\endhead
% content of all footers
\hline
\endfoot
% content of last footer
\hline
\endlastfoot
\citeauthor{shen2009study} & Quantiles & Customer and Transaction Department store & RFM; Customer Lifetime Value; Target Marketing; Data Mining & Retail Store\\ 
\hline
\citeauthor{aggelis2005customer} & Quantiles & E-Banking Dataset & Data Mining; e-banking; RFM analysis & Banking\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The output of the code above:

[image: screenshot of output table]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid intruding into the next cell, you can help latex by suggesting possible hyphenation points for `description`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
Author & Clustering Technique & Dataset & De\-scrip\-tion & Industry\\
\hline
xxx & Quantiles & Customer and Transaction Department store & RFM; Customer Lifetime Value; Target Marketing; Data Mining 
 &  Retail Store \\ 
 \hline
xxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxx & Quantiles & E-Banking Dataset & Data Mining; e-banking; RFM analysis & Banking\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

(if you need the table to allow page breaks, use the `xltabular` package instead)